# controlling hardware back button in Android app

Tags: back-button, mobile-application

I am making a Andriod app. When app starts it shows a loading page and then a selection page .I want that when I press mobile back button on my selection it should take a confirm from user that  "are you sure quit from app " . 
  I try this code but it's not working

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // EDIT
    navigator.app.exitApp(); // exit the app
});
```

Comment: can any one help to solve this problem

Comment: i am using phonegap 0.1.11 to build my app. cordova.js is missing in www/directory .from where i can get this file .

Answer (score 0):

`I have tried this code and its working.`

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`
    `function onDeviceReady() {`
    `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false); //Listen  to the User clicking on the back button`
 `}`

`function onBackKeyDown(e) {`
    `e.preventDefault();`
    `navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?",    onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");`
    `// Prompt the user with the choice`
 `}`

`function onConfirm(button) {`
    `if(button==2){//If User selected No, then we just do nothing`
        `return;`
    `}else{`
        `navigator.app.exitApp();// Otherwise we quit the app.`
    `}`
`}`